# Combinatorics- parking spaces

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 19 adjacent parking spots in a parking lot. Cars cannot be adjacent to each other and there must be an empty spot between two cars. There cannot be more than 2 adjacent spots between cars. How many different ways can cars occupy the lot? Assume cars are identical.

-I know that there is a limitation so the number of empty spaces between cars has to be either one or two. But I'm not sure how to approach this. Could the Stars and Bars method be used?

Comment: What have you tried? How can the cars be parked?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $F_n = F_{n-2} + F_{n-3}$.
Starting conditions are $ F_1 = 1, F_2 = 2, F_3 = 4$.